# C# Dictionary: losing data

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

I'm using Dictionary for data storage in my c# project.

The problem is that in a few hours my Dictionary loses some data. 
Why?

```
public Dictionary<string, AgentHistory> ConnectRequestHistory = new Dictionary<string, AgentHistory>(); //IP - History

public Dictionary<AgentPlayerObject, AgentPlayerData> PlayerDataList = new Dictionary<AgentPlayerObject, AgentPlayerData>(); // AgentPlayerObject - PlayerData
```

When I try getting `PlayerDataList[player].CharName;` after a while, the dictionary has lost it.

Comment: A `Dictionary` does not lose data.  If you put data into a `Dictionary` then it's there until you take it out again.  If the data is not there it's because you took it out.  You must be doing something wrong be there's no way we can guess what that might be.

Comment: Have you checked the AgentPlayerObject class's GetHashCode()-implementation? If it's based on mutable data, and the player is actually mutated, GetHashCode() might return a different hash than it initially returned when the player was added to the Dictionary, which could explain why a subsequent attempt to retrieve it's data fails over time.

Comment: What is the AgentPlayerObject.Equals method looking like? How is PlayerDataList.Count changing over time?

Comment: Are you handling commands concurrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `AgentPlayerObject` is a class and its equality members are not implemented.

Consider implementing equality members:

- [Object.Equals Method (Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- [Object.GetHashCode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also, consider implementing [IEquatable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), i.e. `IEquatable<AgentPlayerObject>`. [If you implement IEquatable you still must override Object’s Equals and GetHashCode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2009/01/15/if-you-implement-iequatable-t-you-still-must-override-object-s-equals-and-gethashcode.aspx):

> IEquatable is a significant improvement over this pattern because it provides a strongly typed equals method.  This protects both the caller and callee from passing incompatible object types.  Additionally it avoids the overhead of boxing for value types.